# TWS job scheduler PAM: Authentication faiiled

Tags: ibm

I am trying ti install TWS 8.5.1 with but I am getting PAM Authentication failed for User:
I have disabled the iptables & selinux;

I am attaching the logs :

```
************ Start Display Current Environment ************
Log file started at: [1/29/12 14:49:54:758 GMT+05:30]
com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:329)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:92)
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.security.WSSecurityException: Pam Authentication failed for user: maestro
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.initialize(ContextManagerImpl.java:2525)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.initialize(ContextManagerImpl.java:2543)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.enable(SecurityContext.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.distSecurityComponentImpl.initialize(distSecurityComponentImpl.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.distSecurityComponentImpl.startSecurity(distSecurityComponentImpl.java:336)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityComponentImpl.startSecurity(SecurityComponentImpl.java:105)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.ServerSecurityComponentImpl.start(ServerSecurityComponentImpl.java:283)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.security.WSSecurityException: Pam Authentication failed for user: maestro
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.getServerSubjectInternal(ContextManagerImpl.java:2195)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.initialize(ContextManagerImpl.java:2513)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSLoginFailedException: Pam Authentication failed for user: maestro
    at com.ibm.ws.security.ltpa.LTPAServerObject.authenticate(LTPAServerObject.java:800)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.server.lm.ltpaLoginModule.login(ltpaLoginModule.java:453)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.common.auth.module.proxy.WSLoginModuleProxy.login(WSLoginModuleProxy.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

[1/29/12 14:50:06:211 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.tws.pam.security.registry.PamUnixRegistryImplNative.checkPassword(PamUnixRegistryImplNative.java:107)
[1/29/12 14:50:06:211 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R   ... 58 more
```

Answer (score 2):

It is written in your log here :

```
Pam Authentication failed for user: maestro
```

You have to make sure that user exist, is not locked and has a password. Try to switch to user maestro by entering its password and start again installation when user is fixed.

Comment: Typically a password is a not strict requirement for service accounts, for root  `su` and similar context changes will work regardless of the existence of a password.  But you **will** get errors when the password is **expired**, `chage -l maestro` might help there.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following link and see if the configuration helps:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21421895

Also, based on the log it looks like it is trying to authenticate as maestro.  Just a note, I have never setup or configured this software.